# Finite state automata minimization

Tags: dfa

I'm trying to model a software agent with these specifications: it simulates a labeling robot that has to label three box that are identified by the positions 1, 2 and 3, he cannot label the same box twice and it starts always in position 1. He can do 2 actions: go_to(X) that moves the robot in the X position and label that label the box in front of him. Note that he as to figure out the best plan, so he can do every path (always without labeling the same box twice).

I modeled the problem as this DFA, where the L on the edges correspond to the action label and the 1, 2, 3 on the edges correspond to the actions go_to(1), go_to(2) and go_to(3). It works but i need a version with around 6 to 8 states.
[the DFA i modeled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtomf.png)

I already minimized the DFA with the known algorithms but i was wondering if it's possible to get even less states by using a different approach.

Comment: Can't you have state transitions where you both perform a move and the label action? Is there really a need to have the intermediate state?

Comment: Your DFA assumes that after moving the only possible action is "L", but this is not stated in your description. You speak of "best plan", but then why do you allow the robot to start with a move without first labeling the start node? That cannot be optimal... On the other hand, you exclude the possibility that the robot moves twice without labeling.

Comment: If you really need all states, then it is clear that there are at least 8 x 3 states, 8 for the possible labeling states, and 3 for where the robot is. So I don't know where you get 6 to 8 from. That latter is only possible if you agree to always label a node when the robot is at a non-labeled node.

Comment: I cannot have just one state for labeling and transition. I didn't state that after moving the only possible action is "L" because if i gave him the opportunity to just cycle through states then it would also be able to label the same box twice. Also he has to figure out the best plan through a markov decision process, but i didn't mention it in the question because it was not necessary.

Comment: Sorry, but I am now even more confused. I didn't suggest to "have just one state for labeling and transition". I suggested to perform 2 actions in a transition. Secondly, you say *"i gave him the opportunity to just cycle through states"*, but there is no problem in having the robot do `goto 2`, and then `goto 3`: it doesn't lead to labeling the same box twice, yet your DFA has no route for this.

Comment: And then, why do you think you only should have 6-8 states? Unless you allow for some restrictions, this is just not possible. We can imagine 24 different states and you have not explained why some of those would not be relevant.